# My photos disappeared from my Samsung S5 SD card. Trying to recover photos or find hidden files

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, photos, samsung-galaxy-s-5, hidden

My photos disappeared from my Samsung S5 SD card.

I know SD cards get corrupted, but there were a couple of weird things that happened in conjunction with the disappearance. I saw a message on my screen briefly saying something about my photos not being gone. About a week later I saw them again just once when I went to look at other photos on the Google + app. I saw a suggestion to try to do a disk check on a computer to recover corrupted files. Disk check says the info cannot be directly accessed.I also have read that some files can be hidden. I need some help with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to My Files, settings, check 'Show Hidden Files'. Now you can see hidden folders beginning with `.` (e.g. `.hidden`) in your device explorer. Check you sd card for such folders beginning with `.` that may contain your files. If not then you can connect your SD card via card reader to your PC and run the Windows app "Recuva" (search Recuva by Piriform) to search for deleted files.
Hope this helps :)